# Why I send data to Django POST but fetch them in GET?

Tags: django, python-3.x, postman

I am new to Django and built a simple test today.

```py
def login_web(request):
    request.encoding = "utf-8"
    print("POST type ", request.method)
    print("body : ", request.body)
    print("POST : ", request.POST)
    print("GET : ", request.GET)
    username = request.POST.get("username")
    password = request.POST.get("password")
    print(username)
    print(password)

    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        print("YR1")
        auth.login(request, user)
        return JsonResponse({"foo": "bar1"})
    else:
        print("IM2")
        return JsonResponse({"foo": "bar2"})
```

I used Postman to send post request to it.

[image]

But the result is very confusing.

```sh
POST type  POST
body :  b''
POST :  <QueryDict: {}>
GET :  <QueryDict: {'username': ['chivier'], 'password': ['123456']}>
None
None
IM2
```

I checked it with request.method, it is sure that I sent a POST request.

I should get them in `request.POST` but why they appear in `request.GET`.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are sending data as `query parameters`. Query parameters are always accessible through `request.GET` it doesn't depend on request type. Send the data in request body and access it through `request.POST`.